# How should a salary negotiation letter look like?

Tags: formatting, typography, templates, letters

Does anyone know if there exists a template for salary negotiation?

Or perhaps how one should look like?

Comment: As tohecz says in his answer, there are several LaTeX templates for letters. The subject of a letter does not really impact on the LaTeX required to create it, and even more general layout issues only link to this site when you want to know _how_ to achieve them in LaTeX, rather than the more general 'is this a good idea' question. As such, I suspect the question is off-topic for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no special classes for such type of a letter. For questions about how to format a letter in general, see for instance:

- [Anyone know a good template for formal letters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158/anyone-know-a-good-template-for-formal-letters)
- [Business letter template with letterhead on the side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55928/business-letter-template-with-letterhead-on-the-side)
- [Looking for Cover letter template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15532/looking-for-cover-letter-template)
- http://www.ctan.org/topic/letter (CTAN list of packages dealing with letters)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letters?sort=votes (Highest-voted [letter](/questions/tagged/letter) tagged questions on this site)

For tips on how to write salary negotiation letters, I would recommend you to post a fresh new question on [Personal Finance and Money.SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/)